# how can i not show a function in header A.h that is used in a function in header B.h but not in main.cpp C++?

Tags: c++

so I have two header file (A.h and B.h) and i include B.h in the main.cpp file

```
//A.h

void foo()
{
    //do something
}
```

```
//B.h
#include "A.h"

void foo1()
{
    foo();
    //do something else
}
```

```
//main.cpp
#include "B.h"

int main()
{
    foo1();
}
```

in my testings i haven't found a way to hide foo() in main
i should also mention that the functions foo() and foo1() are helper function but i want that the only way i can use foo() is when i include directly A.h
is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just separate declarations and implementation in different files and don't include any heraders in `B.h`. If the implementation of the function all becomes part of a single translation unit, the contents of header `A.h` must also be available in `main.cpp`, since otherwise function `foo()` would required by header `B.h`'s `foo1` wouldn't be available..

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution: Don't define (implement) functions in header files, only declare them. Define them in source files.

Then you would have e.g. a header file `A.h`:

```
void foo();
```

A source file `A.cpp`:

```
void foo()
{
    // Do foo stuff...
}
```

And a `B.h` header file:

```
void bar();
```

And a `B.cpp` source file:

```
#include "A.h"

void bar()
{
    // Do bar stuff

    // Call foo
    foo();

    // Do more bar stuff
}
```

Then finally the main source file where you only include `B.h`:

```
#include "B.h"

int main()
{
    bar();

    // Can't call foo, as it's not declared
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to do this?

Yes, you can make use of headers files and source files(.cpp) as shown below.

**A.h**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
//this is a declaration
void foo();
#endif
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
//this is the implementation
void foo()
{
    //do something
}
```

**B.h**

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
//this is a declaration
void foo1();
#endif
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"

//this is implementation
void foo1()
{
    foo();
    //do something else
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
//main.cpp
#include "B.h"

int main()
{
    foo1();
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/GiVnlU1QZ)

##### Note

It is recommended that we should use **header guards** in header files.